# Limit as $x\to -\infty$ for function having square root

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, infinity, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate 
>   $$\lim_{x\to  -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3x^2+2}}{x-2}.$$

My work: when I solved 
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3+2/x^2}}{1-2/x}$$
I got answer $\sqrt{3}$ 
but if we take $|x|$ then I got $-\sqrt{3}$
what should be answer ?
$\sqrt{3}$ or $-\sqrt{3}$ ?

Comment: Just a comment, you can take the limit to $+\infty$ if you just change all $x$ to $-x$.

Or, in other words, make a substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y:=-x.$

Now consider:

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{3y^2 +2}}{-y-2}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and, for $x<0$, $|x|=-x$. Therefore, as $x\to -\infty$,
$$\frac{\sqrt{3x^2+2}}{x-2}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{3+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{x(1-\frac{2}{x})}=\frac{|x|\sqrt{3+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{x(1-\frac{2}{x})}=-\frac{\sqrt{3+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{1-\frac{2}{x}}\to -\sqrt{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

write $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{|x|}{x}\frac{\sqrt{3+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{1-\frac{2}{x}}$$